# Uncaught Type Error in magento 2 and 404 error

Tags: magento2, css, json, static-content

I've been attempting to set up Magento 2 on a WAMP server and have ran into a few errors. My Magento UI doesn't look right and I have 2 errors in the error log (When you F12 the page).

"Uncaught TypeError: require is not a function"

AND

"GET http://localhost/Magento2/pub/static/version1533909984/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js 404 (Not Found)"

I have attempted to solve these errors by using several commands such as:

1.) php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy

2.) php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production

3.)  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

however they have had no affect at all. If i'm not mistaken, I believe the error lies with setting up static content but I am probably wrong. Every command and change I have made has had no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Some commands that i have tried]

[image: Image of what my UI looks like and the magento error log]

[image]

Comment: So Delete in /pub/static except .htaccess and /var then run below commands php bin/magento setup:di:compile and php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: I get an 'out of memory error' (see image 3). I've changed all my memory values in php.ini as well.

Comment: run the below commands php -dmemorylimit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile php -dmemorylimit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix memory limit problem by editing `app/bootstrap.php` , just add following code at the start of the file ;

```
ini_set('memory_limit', -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command in Magento root directory

Below command for Magento files and directory permissions

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml;
```

Below command deploy static content, compile code, indexing content and clear cache

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Thank you.